# Variable not properly updating when searching for consecutive primes

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Consider the following script:

`Python`

```
def f(a, b, n):
    return (n ** 2) + (a * n) + b


def prime_check(num):
    for i in range(2, (num // 2) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
    

num_primes = []
coefficients = []
for a in range(-999, 1000, 1):
    for b in range(-1000, 1001, 1):
        n = 0
        coefficients.append((a, b))
        while True:
            result = prime_check(f(a, b, n))
            if result:
                n += 1
                continue
            else:
                num_primes.append(n - 1)
                break
        print(f"num_primes: {num_primes[-1]} coefficients: {coefficients[-1]}")
```

The algorithm above is meant to search values of |a| < 1000 , |b| <= 1000, for function f(a, b, n), where  n = 0 to start, and increments if f(a, b, n) returns a prime number. It keeps incrementing n and checking for primes until f returns a non-prime.

At this point, n - 1 is appended to num_primes to reflect the number of primes this set of coefficients (a, b) produced for consecutive values of n.

When I run this code, the print statement at the end of the inner for loop shows num_primes values are stuck alternating between whatever value b is for the current iteration and 0, rather than the proper number of primes for the coefficients.

I'm not sure where I went wrong here.

Comment: Try `print(f"a={a} b={b} n={n} f()={f(a,b,n)} isprime={result}")` before `if result:`

Comment: `f(a, b, n)` often gives negative numbers. `prime_check(num)` of a negative number always returns `True` because the loop in `for i in range(2, negative_number)` stops without entering the loop.

Comment: @JohanC YES thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @JohanC, when `prime_check(num)` was given a negative number, it would return True no matter what the number was.

The fix for this was to make a simple change to `prime_check(num)` as shown below.

`Python`

```
def prime_check(num):
    for i in range(2, (abs(num) // 2) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

By calculating `abs(num)` before division, we eliminate the bad behavior when num < 0.